# A Servlet Container on top of Hadoop?

Tags: servlets, hadoop

i'm on the architectural phase of a big project and i've decided to use hbase as my database, and will use map/reduce jobs for my processing so my architecture works totally under hadoop.

The thing is i also need to implement some REST, SOAP API's some web pages too so i was thinking is there any servlet container that runs on top of hadoop so that my system stays redundant and distributed without worrying about a secondary cluster machenism(since i allready setup one for hadoop).

So is there any servlet container that runs on top of hadoop, like hbase(a database) runs on top of hadoop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

seems like there is no servlet container that runs on top of hadoop yet. This probably wont ever happen since hadoop/hbase are used for processing big data behind the scenes and not expected to work as fast as a RDBMS which is used for a web application.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite a servlet, but you may be interested in the REST interface to HBase provided by [Stargate](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate). There is also a [Thrift interface](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi).

Regards,
Jeff

Comment: i'm am going to check Stargate but i do not think it runs inside Hadoop cluster as a distributed REST interface on all Hadoop nodes or does it?