# org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not a subtype

Tags: java, hadoop

Getting this exception with Hadoop 2.5.1 when used inside a HTTP servlet

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not a subtype
```

The DistributedFileSystem class could be found in these jars

```
hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
hadoop-hdfs-2.5.1.jar
```

When I use hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar alone, the compiler error I get is that hdfs schema not found.

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
```

When I use both jars I get the aforementioned error.

The code inside the servlet:

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    try {
        System.out.println("keyword=" + keyWord);
        conf.set("keyword", keyWord);
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", 
                org.apache.hadoop.fs.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName()
            );

        Job job = Job.getInstance();
        job.setJarByClass(HadoopServlet.class);

        job.setJobName("Tomcat Log Error");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://master:54310/keyword/pg20417.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://master:54310/tmp/output" + uuid));
        job.setMapperClass(TomcatLogErrorMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TomcatLogErrorReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Found this thread

[A Servlet Container on top of Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970485/a-servlet-container-on-top-of-hadoop)

Looks like one can't use a servlet to run hadoop jobs.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue ?? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because hdfs schema is registered in hadoop-hdfs.jar, so you can't just use hadoop-core.jar alone.

It looks like your running servlet thread's context class loader can't load org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem, you can try this:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```